# How to prevent editing of GXT ComboBoxCell

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have added a ComboBoxCell on a Grid. Problem is when user select an element from ComboBoxCell then after selection the ComboBoxCell is not blurred and text box present in ComboBoxCell still shows cursor.
So because of this an Image (which is a button for me) present on same row of GXT grid doesnt fire browse event because ComboBoxCell has the focus right now. Only when ComboBoxCell is blurred then browseEvent is fired on click of image.
Any solution how can i blur the ComboBoxCell or how can I remove editing in ComboBoxCell Textbox?

```
test.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL); 
         test.setWidth(100);     
         test.setSelectOnFocus(true);//doesnot work
         test.setForceSelection(true);//doesnot work
```

Issue exist in sencha example as well
http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid
On selection element from ComboBoxCell and Click on button then even doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBoxCell extends [AbstractEditableCell](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/cell/core/client/form/ComboBoxCell.html). That is why you are getting the edit option.

Use [SelectionCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/SelectionCell.html) instead.